# Adding event to phones calendar on ios (xamarin forms)

Tags: javascript, ios, xamarin, calendar, icalendar

I'm building my first mobile app using Xamarin forms. It's basically just a frame for webview containing web application (c#). In this app there is possibility to add event to phones calendar.

For IOS only way i have got it to work is to pop that page to safari and redirect it to ics file generated just earlier. That works fine BUT it leaves empty window in safari and returns user to it after adding the event. Customers wants user to come back to app after calendar.

How can i
a) do it differently so i dont have to pop user to safari at all (that would be best)
b) close the window and navigate back to app (i can open the app from web site  but window that has opened the file obviously has no where to put the code).

Im not much of a coder and this is killing me so please help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the DateChange Event in your view:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle b)
{
    base.OnCreate(b);
    // create event handler 
    var calendar = FindViewById<CalendarView>(Resource.Id.myCalender);
    calendar.DateChange += CalendarOnDateChange;
}
```

//Event method

```
private void CalendarOnDateChange(object sender, CalendarView.DateChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var newdatetime = new DateTime(args.Year, args.Month, args.DayOfMonth);
}
```

Comment: I dont see how that helps? How do i implement it or get info for the event to calendar?